# Perspective warp plane not showing - Photoshop cc

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, perspective

Am working in perspective warp in photoshop but cannot see the grid plane that is usually visible. The corners are showing but far off from the grid created which is weird.  Am wondering if there is a preference that needs to be turned on or could also potentially be the machine I'm using at work does not have the capacity as my laptop at home it seems to work fine.
[image]